# Bootstraping operating system settings after reinstall

Tags: python, linux, bash

I like to change my operating system. I also frequently format it when it becomes cluttered and restore needed files from backup. I started to develop my tiny script in bash that automatizes some of those tasks, like adding repositories, installing software, setting up wallpaper and panels and so on. Unfortunately, this bash script is getting less and less readable. I was wondering, what language could I pick, so that after reinstalling operating system I will be able to copy my little program from pendrive, run it and let it do whole work for me.

Most of programming languages require to install some kind of running environment (let's take java and JRE as an example). This is why I am focusing on languages, that can be run immediately after installing operating system. As I am only using GNU/Linux systems, bash was an obvious choice. But readability is a downside. I thought about Python, but some operating systems have 2.X and some 3.X.

What can I do, to create tiny generic program, that will work on most Linux based operating systems?

I know, that this is pretty much hard question without specifying those operating systems, but I simply do not know what operating system will I use in future (beside fact, that it will be mainstream Linux OS). We can assume, that it is enough if it can run on at least 80 of 100 operating systems listed on distrowatch.com.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww I was going to post it on Super User, however my main question is how to create program, so it thought that Stackoverflow would fit better. Anyway, please move it to Super User or Unix/Linux if You are able to.

Comment: You can flag the question and ask the moderators move it so you don't have to delete it on one site and create it on another site. It also resets the question's score. For whatever reasons, the Stack Exchange network does not allow you to migrate it yourself. Also see [Author initiated migration to other SE sites?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254851)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely learn basic C++.

You really just have to learn `<iostream>`'s `std::cout`, `std::cin`, `std::endl` and the `<csysio>`'s `system()` function for executing commands.

Pros:

- It's available for every Linux system.
- It's *far* more extensible than Bash.
- You can compile your program using static linking so that it doesn't need ANY dependency on a new system.

Cons:

- Harder to learn.
- Have to compile the code.

Comment: I already know (some of) C++, however it does not satisfy requirement of copying file and just running it. I would have to compile it myself first. On the other hand, if I would like to compile it before reinstall, it would not be portable. Middle ground that is keeping multiple binaries is becoming burden as much as bash script. But beside that this is a viable alternative - thanks.

Comment: If you link statically, especially if you make a 32-bit executable, it should work across every Linux distribution without needing to worry about dependencies.